# Debug for multiple servers in the load balance

Tags: java, intellij-idea, load-balancing, remote-debugging

I have multiple servers in the load balance, I have debug mode only for one from them. Debug can join random, because request doesn't put on debug server. How can I debug in this circumstances?

edit: I can't recreate the issue locally. I can use log of course, but may be exist better way for it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. What about enabling debug log mode and find out exact location? then you can run locally and recreate that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way for resolve my problem. "Loadbalancer" uses variable for identification server, it is saved in cookies. I can use value of variable in my browser. EditThisCookie or anything else can help in it.